# Error in bison : ‘yyval.YYSTYPE::expr’ does not have class type

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a flex/bison program and I am facing many errors. I did not find any answers online about these errors even if I think it might be easy to understand them.
Here is my lex code:

```
%{
#include "my_type.hpp"
#include "bison.tab.h"
%}
/* ... */
%%
{int} {
    yylval.val=strdup(yytext);
    return(NOMBRE);
}
/* other pattern */
{id} {
    yylval.val=strdup(yytext);
    return(ID);
}
%%
```

And the bison file:

```
%{
#include "my_type.hpp"
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *s);
int yyparse();
void yy_scan_string(char*);
%}

%union{
    char* val;
    Expr_t expr();
};
%type <val> Scalar
%type <expr> Expression

%token <val> ID NOMBRE
/* other token and precedence*/
%start Input
%%
/* rules... and the two that create issues*/
Scalar:  
      NOMBRE                        /* return char* */
    | ID /*int or define*/          /* return char* */
;
Expression:
      Scalar                        {$$.add($1);}
    | Expression PLUS Expression    {$$.add($1).add($3);}
    | Expression MINUS Expression   {$$.add($1).add("-").add($3);}
%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    printf("err: %s\n",s);
}
```

finally, the "type" file:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct Expr_t{
    vector<string> expr;

    Expr_t& add(char* s){
        expr.push_back(string(s));
        return *this;
    }

    Expr_t& add(Expr_t& e){
        expr.insert(expr.end(), e.expr.begin(), e.expr.end());
    }
};
```

When I compile (Bison 3.0.4, Flex 2.6.0 and G++ 5.4.0) the program `bison -d bison.y ; flex flex.lex ; g++ -std=c++11 bison.tab.c lex.yy.c my_main.cpp -ll` I get many errors of this kind (in my real program, I have more than just the type "Expr", but all the errors are the same with different name):

`bison.y: In function ‘int yyparse()’: ‘yyval.YYSTYPE::expr’ does not have class type
Scalar      {$$.add($1);}`

EDIT______________
I tried with :

```
%union{
    char* val;
    Expr_t* expr;
};

Expression:
      Scalar    {$$->add($1);}
```

But I get `Expr_t does not name a type`.

Answer: I forget to include the "type.h" in the flex file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Expr_t expr();
```

declares the union member `expr` to be a function of no arguments returning an `Expr_t`. As the error message says, that is not a class type and it does not have an `add` member. Probably, you meant

```
    Expr_t expr;
```

although that will probably cause a different error since `Expr_t` is not POD and cannot be a union member.

Comment: Indeed, I used the "()" thinking that it needed a construction of the object (that's stupid but hey, I was desperate).
It seems that classical Flex/bison can't hold class so I'm heading to C++ flex/bison, hoping it will do the trick. Otherwise I will be forced to use global variable even if it is awful...

Comment: @viridya: you could always use a pointer. Or with bison's c++ api, you could use a variant instead of a union. I don't think that a vector of strings is what you want, anyway. An expression will normally have expressions as children, and that requires a pointer.

Comment: I really need a vector of strings for some reason but thank very much for the pointer solution. I did not think of that. You just save me (because otherwise, I was planing to use C array with realloc and it would have been just awful).
Thanks again